# Bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber Problem

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, javacv

I use the following method to get an array of frames that I can use in other parts of the program. But I encounter OutOfMemoryError.But I encounter OutOfMemoryError.
Is there a way I can do it?

```
 public  Frame[] grabFrame(String videoPath) throws FFmpegFrameGrabber.Exception
    {
        FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoPath);
        grabber.start();
        
       
        final Frame[] frames = new Frame[grabber.getLengthInFrames()];
        int flag = 0;
        int index =0;
        Frame frame = null;
        while (flag < frames.length)
        {
             frame = grabber.grab().clone();
            
            


            if(frame!=null)
            {

                frames[index] = frame.clone();
                index++;

            }
            flag++;
        }
        
        
        grabber.stop();
        grabber.release();
        return frames;
    }
```

output:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot allocate new BytePointer(6174720): totalBytes = 2014M, physicalBytes = 2155M

Comment: The obvious solution: Don't try to decode and keep all the frames of a video in memory at once. Instead process each frame, or a fixed number of frames at a time. Finally, you should probably only `clone()` the frame once to avoid wasting memory/put extra strain on the GC. If you for some reason *need* to keep all the frames decoded in memory, the only other option is to allocate more memory for the Java process...

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your frames somewhere because your application cannot hold them all in memory.

You could use a relatively temp db like Redis depending on your use case. It's difficult to say without understanding what you need to do with the data you are consuming.

Comment: My goal is to make a movie editor. To do this, I need to have the forms in memory and display and process them for the user at the same time. So that the user can move between frames and make the desired changes. And I need to do this quickly. Can this be done using the temp db?